# Docker swarm mode - no published ports on worker nodes

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying out the docker warm mode on a couple of VirtualBoxes. 
I create the swarm on the manager with

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.15.4 --listen-addr 192.168.15.4
```

Joining a worker node works perfectly. So I have one manager node and one worker node. Then I'm deploying two services with published ports (one with published port 3306 for mysql and another with published port 3000 for a node.js application).

```
docker service create --name mysqlbox --publish 3306:3306 mysqlimage
docker service create --name nodebox --publish 3000:3000 nodeimage
```

Now the problem is that the service which is running on the manager node exposes its port correcty so i can connect to it with `curl docker-manager:3306` but the service running on the worker node doesn't expose its port (3000) to the host, so i can't connect to it with `curl docker-worker:3000`. I also read, that if the port is published it should be available on all nodes, but this doesnt work.
Checked everything with `netstat`. On manager node the port (3306) is visible but no port 3000 on any other node.
The same happens if the node.js service on the manager node and the mysql service runs on the worker node. Then the port for the node.js service is published on the manager node and I'm not able to connect to the mysql service on the worker node.

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: I deploy nginx with swarm mode in two nodes. The publish port is 8080, thw two nodes exist 8080 port listening, but only manager node can arrive using curl command. Maybe you can see whether you start multi container using `docker service ps <service-name>`

Comment: try to stop firewall(d) on docker host

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an overlay network to allow access to the worker nodes.

[Overlay] https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/networking/#create-an-overlay-network